# Integration by Substitution (clueless)

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

So there is this question that I have come across. Not sure how to deal with it.

$$\int e^{\secπx} \secπx\tanπx dx $$

Do I use integration by parts instead and have $\sec \pi x$ as $u$ and $\tan \pi x$ as $v$?

Comment: **Hint:** The integrand has the form $$e^u\frac 1{\pi}du$$ where $u=\sec x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitution works fine here! $\frac{d}{dx}\sec(x)=\sec(x)\tan(x)$ so using the substitution $u=\sec(\pi x)$ we get that this integral is equal to $$\frac{1}{\pi}\int e^udu=\frac{1}{\pi}e^{\sec(\pi x)}+C$$

Comment: Its really that simple? because secπx appears a few times I thought it would be more complicated. Thank you

Comment: @Shauna Yup! It's really that simple.